# Python com django está dando problema ao migrar um modelo

Tags: python, django, migrations

> C:\Programas Python\mysite>python manage.py makemigrations polls
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "manage.py", line 22, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 337, in execute
>       django.setup()
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 27, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
>       app_config.import_models()
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
>       self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in 
>       from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in 
>       class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in **new**
>       new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 330, in add_to_class
>       value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
>       self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py", line 33, in **getattr**
>       return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 212, in **getitem**
>       conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py", line 184, in **init**
>       super(DatabaseWrapper, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 97, in **init**
>       self.creation = self.creation_class(self)
>   TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
>       'NoneType' object is not callable

Ao emitir este erro pode ser algum problema com a conexão?

Abaixo as configurações do banco de dados que estou usando o Django e o modelo que editei do `polls`.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'MS_PYTHON',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': 'UDILAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'vorlon',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'provider': 'SQLOLEDB',
            'use_mars': True,
            }
    }
}
```

**models.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Provavelmente a biblioteca que você está usando pra conectar com o banco de dados (sqlserver_ado) foi feita para uma versão mais antiga do Django, e não funciona com as versões mais recentes (que usam migrations). Segundo [essa resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43660010/520779) esse erro costuma acontecer quando você tenta mexer no banco antes do settings.py estar totalmente carregado (o que não era problema até o 1.6, passou a ser após o 1.7). Mas pelo seu traceback, não me parece ser código seu que esteja fazendo isso, por isso eu desconfio que seja a biblioteca mesmo...